# Change event is not triggering for JSONModel

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel, javascript-databinding

I have model called resources i need to listen to the change event i have attached the binding as below

```
var resModel = this.getModel("resources");
var resBinding = new Binding(resModel, "resources>/resources", resModel.getContext("/resources"));
resBinding.attachChange(this._resourceChanged.bind(this));
```

When I add the data to the model as below, change event is not triggered

```
var resources = this.getModel("resources").getProperty("/resources");
resources.push({
                 "res_num": 18,
                 "name": "New Added"
               });
this.getModel("resources").setProperty("/resources", resources);
```

But first time when i add the data to model it is triggering

```
this.resourceModel.setData({
  'resources': resources
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a Binding with a BindingContext like you do here

```
new Binding(resModel, "resources>/resources", resModel.getContext("/resources"));
```

in my understanding you actually create a binding to "resources>/resources//resources". When using a BindingContext the binding path should be relative (no leading "/"):

```
new Binding(resModel, "resources>resources", resModel.getContext("/resources"));
```

But most probably you don't even need a Context here so that this will be sufficient:

```
new Binding(resModel, "resources>resources");
```

Note that `sap.ui.model.Binding` is abstract and you might need to use `sap.ui.model.PropertyBinding` or `sap.ui.model.ListBinding` depending on the watched property being a plain property or an array.

So why does your "change" still trigger initially? I guess that setData will just trigger ALL change listeners or your initial data fits the structure that you accidentally bound.

I haven't tested the above. If you provide a JSBin that will be an easy thing to do.

BR
Chris

Comment: it its working with JSBin but not in my code https://jsbin.com/dotexiyaqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: even if i use setData insted of setProperty its not triggering

Comment: i found the problem in my code.. its because these are 2 different object because of that it was not triggering.